# Django - form not validating

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-views

I'm new to Django. I'm working on a project of building an online purchasing system. This form for some reason can not be validated. Attached the code below. Please let me know if you need more information:

url.py

```py
app_name = 'vip'
urlpatterns = [
    path('create-order/', views.create_vip_order, name='create-vip-order'),
    path('order/<int:pk>/', views.VipOrderDetailView.as_view(), name='vip-order'),
]
```

models.py

```py
class VipOrder(models.Model):
    ref_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, unique=True, verbose_name=_("VIP Order Number"))
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_("VIP Order Active?"))
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Your name'))
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Your email'))
    phone = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Your cell phone number'))
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name=_('What is your address?'))
    item_description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Describe the item briefly"))
    item_image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='vip_order', verbose_name=_("Upload a photo of the item"))
    item_image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='vip_order', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("Upload another photo of the item (optional)"))
    item_image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='vip_order', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("Upload another photo of the item (optional)"))

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = _('VIP Order')
        verbose_name_plural = _('VIP Orders')
        ordering = ['-date_created']

    def __str__(self):
        return "VIP Order No. {}".format(self.ref_number)
```

form.py

```py
class VipOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = VipOrder
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'address', 'item_description',
                  'item_image1', 'item_image2', 'item_image3']
```

views.py

```py
def create_vip_order(request, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VipOrderForm(data=request.POST)

        print('form filled with POST data') # executed on POST request

        print(form.is_valid()) # always False here for some reason??

        if form.is_valid():
            new_vip_order = form.save(commit=False)
            print('order created') # never executed

            new_vip_order.active = True
            print('order activated') # never executed

            new_vip_order.ref_number = vip_ref_number_generator()
            print('order ref number generated') # never executed

            new_vip_order.save()
            print('order saved') # never executed

            messages.info(request, _(
                "Thanks for your purchase, we will contact you soon!"))

            return redirect('vip:vip-order', new_vip_order.pk)

    form = VipOrderForm()
    print('form initiated') # executed both 'GET' and 'POST' request
    return render(request, "vip/create_vip_order.html", {'form': form})
```

#### Please see the notes above.

I think the problem might be somewhere between the `views.py` and the template? Because I *CAN* create an instance of the model in admin.

create_vip_order.html

```html
<div class="px-2">
        <p>{% trans "Please provide your information and the description of the item you'd like to purchase" %}.</p>
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'vip:create-vip-order' %}"
            class="border-top pt-4 col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 mr-auto ml-auto">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% bootstrap_form form %}
            <button type="submit" class="mt-3 btn btn-outline-info col-12 mb-5">{% trans "Place Order" %}</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: What form errors are shown?

Comment: no errors shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pheww! Found the answer in [this post on GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/imagefield-django-forms/)

2 missing code:

1. `form = VipOrderForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`, `request.FILES` is to handle the files uploaded. Because of that, the form could not be validated, for the missing file...
2. This is what I found on GeeksforGeeks: part missing in the `form` tag: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, [the official doc: binding uploaded files to a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form)